# Binding to original this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is as follows:

```
{ except: player => ({ send :player.getSocket().broadcast.emit }) }
```

However this means that the `this` in the emit function is not the one it expects it to be (the `broadcast` object).

So I can do:

```
{ except: player => ({ send : (msg, data) => player.getSocket().broadcast.emit(msg, data) }) }
```

But this is ugly, especially if the arguments change.
So the alternative is:

```
{ except: player => ({ send : (t = player.getSocket().broadcast).emit.bind(t) }) }
```

But is there a tidier way of doing this, of assigning a function to an object while maintaining it's `this` as it's parent object.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify who `this` will be by calling the function with [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). The first parameter to these methods will be `this` within the body of the function.

Comment: I don't want to actually call the function here though.

Comment: True, so your `.bind ` syntax seems the most appropriate. The problem is that you need to create a closure in order to capture the thing that you consider the parent. I don't think there's a way around that as [`this` is very weird in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/292921).

Answer (score 0):

Using `bind` in order to maintain the scope of `this` is actually a good solution to your problem, the way I see it, it makes the code a lot more understandable because you can know to what object the function actually belongs, by using `apply` or `call`, when you read the code you wont know to what `this` the function/method belongs. As far as i know, `bind` is a pretty good solution to your problem here.